# Approximation ratio of LP relaxation of Max Coverage Problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

For the instance of the relaxed [Max Coverage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem) given by the linear program below:

$$
\begin{cases}
\sum_{i = 1}^ny_i \to \max \\
\sum_{j = 1}^m x_j = k \\
y_i \leq \sum_{j : i \in S_j}x_j, i\in[1, n] \\
0 \leq y_i, x_j \leq 1, i\in[1, n], j \in [1, n]\
\end{cases}
$$

I found that approximation ratio is exactly $1 - 1/e + o(1)$. But what about the design of the worst case input for which this distance between integer and rational cases optimums is achieved? Can you help me to build such an input for this problem?